# Is it possible to add hyperlinks/deeplinks to images in Apple PassKit?

Tags: ios, apple-wallet

I'm currently exploring the capabilities of custom passes in Apple Wallet.

One thing I would like to do is enable users to be able to go to my website if they click their gift card's icon.

[image: Gift Card]

However, after looking through the documentation - there doesn't seem to be any support for this basic ask.

The closest thing I was able to find was [adding URLs to the back of the custom passes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210664/apple-wallet-formerly-passbook-best-way-to-add-links). Anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the same thing.
I'm surprised people praise Apple Wallet passes that much, when it's really bad to work with.

Everything is file based, and you have to create a physical zip-file.

Google's approach is much better imho: everything is done via an API, so the pass itself is just a url with a token. Sharing a Google Pass is so much simpler and works everywhere.

Updating a pass is simple; just call the Google Api and everything will be ok. Images and assets are urls. Much much better to work with.

Updating an Apple pass involves fricking Push notifications, it's mind bogglingly complex compared to Google's solution.

Oh well

Comment: Sorry, Apple can't do that. They are too busy rent seeking 30% from developers on their app store.

Comment: Basically what I would do is: fetch the icon from a url, convert to the correct 1x, 2x sizes, save them locally on the server (serving as a primitive cache if you will). Then use those. Wrap it in a function so you just call it with the url, and in return gets the resources